# java sql + check true/false

Tags: java, sql, try-catch

I have problem ; / 
I set in global variable :

```
public static boolean wystawianie;
```

On other button i set to this variable true.
But this if dont see this true/false...
This code do always :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Faktura została wystawiona poprawnie");
dispose();
```

Kod:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {

                if(zmienne.wystawianie = true)
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Faktura została wystawiona poprawnie");
                dispose();  

            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/faktury";
                    String userid = "root";
                    String password = "w4t3q99j";

                    Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection( url, userid, password );
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    String sql = "DROP DATABASE "+zmienne.a+"";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                    System.out.println("usuniete");


                }
                catch(Exception e3)
                {
                    System.out.println(e3);
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Faktura została nie zapisana");
                dispose();  
            }

            }
        });
```

Anyone know why ? ^^

Comment: You are setting it to true in your code: `if(zmienne.wystawianie = true)`. It should be `if(zmienne.wystawianie)`

Answer (score 1):

This statement:
`if(zmienne.wystawianie = true)`

sets the value of `zmienne.wystawianie` to true.

You should use:

`if(zmienne.wystawianie)`

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing assignment(single=) instead of comparison(==) here:

```
            if(zmienne.wystawianie = true)
```

Change it to:

```
            if(zmienne.wystawianie == true)
```